# How to delete a range of emails in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I want to delete a date range of emails (from jan 2011-sept 2011). I do NOT want to delete all my emails, and I would rather not have to do it page by page. (100 conversations at a time) Is this possible?

Answer (score 12):

1. Use the [advanced search operators](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190) `before:` and `after:` to select your date range in the search

   [image: search operators]
2. Click the "select all" checkbox

   [image: select checkbox]
3. Click the link to "Select all conversations that match this search"
   [image: "conversations selected" message]
4. Note that all conversations are now selected
   [image: "all conversations selected" message]
5. Click <kbd>Delete</kbd>

Done! If you want them "gone" gone at this point, empty your "Trash".

Do note that this selects conversations, not individual messages. If a conversation spans your start or end date you might catch things you didn't intend. (Obviously of no concern if you have turned off conversation view.)

Comment: If conversation view is disabled, the link will read "Select all messages that match this search" rather than "Select all conversations that match this search".

Comment: I'm selecting "Select all conversations that match this search", but it only deletes a batch of emails from my search at a time. I'm having to repeat the process over and over :P

Answer (score 4):

Type `older_than:Xy` into search (X being the value in years that you want to highlight and eventually delete. You can also do months or days by using m or d instead of y.)

Press select all button in the upper left hand of the inbox.

When all of the entries on that page are highlighted, a line that says "All 50 conversations on this page are selected. Select all conversations that match this search."

[image]

Press delete.

[image]